# 3D wrapper for turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, coordinate-system, wrapper, turtle-graphics

I am a Python enthusiast, but I'm never sure if what I'm doing is Pythonic. I have made my own graphics wrapper for Python's turtle. I don't entirely know if I did this right, so I have come here for suggestions to make it run faster or improve the code in any way.

```python3
from turtle import *
from math import cos, sin, radians, atan


faceOn = False #These are metadata. Don't know what they're actually called.
active2D = []
active3D = []
activeLines = []
activeFaces = []
activeFacesTemp = []


def getpixels():
    return active2D


def getverts():
    return active3D


def getlines():
    return activeLines


def getfaces():
    return activeFaces


def begin(name, swidth, sheight):
    title(name)
    tracer(0,0)
    screensize(swidth, sheight)
    shapesize(1 / 20, 1 / 20)
    shape('square')
    ht()
    penup()
    update()


def Tcos(angle):
    return cos(radians(angle))


def Tsin(angle):
    return sin(radians(angle))


def rotate(vert, rot):
    x,y,z = vert
    Rx,Ry,Rz = rot
    Ca,Cb,Cc = [Tcos(Rx), Tcos(Ry), Tcos(Rz)]
    Sa,Sb,Sc = [Tsin(Rx), Tsin(Ry), Tsin(Rz)]

    return [((x * Cb * Cc) + ((y * Sa * Sb * Cc) + (y * Ca * Sc)) + ((z * -Ca * Sb * Cc) + (z * Sa * Sc))),
            ((x * -Cb * Sc) + ((y * -Sa * Sb * Sc) + (y * Ca * Cc)) + ((z * Ca * Sb * Sc) + (z * Sa * Cc))),
            ((x * Sb) + (y * -Sa * Cb) + (z * Ca * Cb))]


def translate(vert, trans):
    out = []
    for x,y in zip(vert, trans):
        out.append((x + y))
    return out


def exits(string):
    valid = {"OnClick":exitonclick, "Now":bye}
    if string not in valid:
        raise ValueError("Not a valid exit type")
    else:
        valid[string]()


def pix(point,upd):
    goto(point[0], point[1])
    stamp()
    if upd == True:
        update()
    active2D.append([point, upd])


def vertex(point,fov,czd,upd):
    x,y,z = vertdata(point)
    pix([((-x * 2) / ((z / fov) - czd)), ((-y * 2) / ((z / fov) - czd))], upd)
    active3D.append([point,[x,y,z],[fov,czd,upd]])


def vertdata(point):
    return translate(rotate(point[0],point[1]),point[2])


def face_point(point,fov,czd):
    x,y,z = vertdata(point)
    if faceOn == True:
        activeFacesTemp.append([point, [x, y, z], [fov, czd, upd]])
    goto(((-x * 2) / ((z / fov) - czd)), ((-y * 2) / ((z / fov) - czd)))


def line(pointA,pointB,fov,czd,upd):
    dataA,dataB = [vertdata(pointA), vertdata(pointB)]
    Ax,Ay = [((-dataA[0] * 2) / ((dataA[2] / fov) - czd)), ((-dataA[1] * 2) / ((dataA[2] / fov) - czd))]
    Bx,By = [((-dataB[0] * 2) / ((dataB[2] / fov) - czd)), ((-dataB[1] * 2) / ((dataB[2] / fov) - czd))]
    if not (Bx - Ax) == 0:
        setheading(atan((By - Ay)/(Bx - Ax)))
    else:
        setheading(90)
    goto(Ax,Ay)
    pendown()
    goto(Bx,By)
    penup()
    activeLines.append([[pointA, pointB],
                       [[dataA[0], dataA[1], dataA[2]],
                       [dataB[0],dataB[1],dataB[2]]],[fov,czd,upd]])

def start_face(color):
    fillcolor(color)
    begin_fill()
    faceOn = True

def end_face():
    end_fill()
    activeFaces.append(activeFacesTemp)
    activeFacesTemp.clear()
    faceOn = False

def flush(): #Used to empty the get...() methods, as well as clear the screen. Make sure to always use this instead of calling clear() from turtle.
    active2D.clear()
    activeLines.clear()
    activeFaces.clear()
    active3D.clear()
    clear() #not listype.clear(), but a turtle method to clear the window.

def tick(x):
    for q in range(x * 1000):
        pass


def refresh():
    update()



def example():
    s = start_face
    f = face_point
    e = end_face
    fov,czd = [500,5]
    tra = [0,0,0]
    x,y,z = [200,200,200]
    for q in range(0,1440):
        rot = [q,q,q]
        vertA = [[x,y,z],rot,tra]
        vertB = [[-x,y,z],rot,tra]
        vertC = [[x,-y,z],rot,tra]
        vertD = [[-x,-y,z],rot,tra]
        vertE = [[x,y,-z],rot,tra]
        vertF = [[-x,y,-z],rot,tra]
        vertG = [[x,-y,-z],rot,tra]
        vertH = [[-x,-y,-z],rot,tra]

        flush()
        f(vertE,fov,czd) #Faces first for translucency. Make sure all faces are the same color if Z buffer is not programmed.
        s("Blue")
        f(vertE,fov,czd)
        f(vertF,fov,czd)
        f(vertH,fov,czd)
        f(vertG,fov,czd)
        e()

        f(vertA,fov,czd) #Second Face
        s("Blue")
        f(vertA,fov,czd)
        f(vertB,fov,czd)
        f(vertD,fov,czd)
        f(vertC,fov,czd)
        e()

        f(vertC,fov,czd) #Third Face
        s("Blue")
        f(vertC,fov,czd)
        f(vertD,fov,czd)
        f(vertH,fov,czd)
        f(vertG,fov,czd)
        e()

        f(vertA,fov,czd) #Forth Face
        s("Blue")
        f(vertA,fov,czd)
        f(vertB,fov,czd)
        f(vertF,fov,czd)
        f(vertE,fov,czd)
        e()

        f(vertA,fov,czd) #Yay! All faces are done! We don't need a sixth face because it will always be covered by the other five.
        s("Blue")
        f(vertA,fov,czd)
        f(vertC,fov,czd)
        f(vertG,fov,czd)
        f(vertE,fov,czd)
        e()


        line(vertC,vertD,fov,czd,False) #Line definitions. Make sure you do this first so you have an idea on the faces.
        line(vertA,vertB,fov,czd,False)
        line(vertB,vertD,fov,czd,False)
        line(vertA,vertC,fov,czd,False)
        line(vertD,vertH,fov,czd,False)
        line(vertC,vertG,fov,czd,False)
        line(vertE,vertG,fov,czd,False)
        line(vertA,vertE,fov,czd,False)
        line(vertH,vertF,fov,czd,False)
        line(vertB,vertF,fov,czd,False)
        line(vertH,vertG,fov,czd,False)
        line(vertF,vertE,fov,czd,False)


        refresh()
```

Comment: Do you want style judgements too? Or just speed?

Comment: @Riker Whatever you don't mind doing, I'm open too. I'm prioritizing speed but if you don't mind style judgments you can add those in too.

Comment: What's with the indenting in `face_point`?

Comment: @Riker sorry I accidentally provided an error-laiden version before my latest revision. It should be good now